# maximum width setting not working for row

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

i am using ZF6. i am using the SASS version.
now created a new row.
it's width is set to

```
max-width: 75rem;
```

I tried to change the row width in `css` but it doesn't work.
I also tried to change the variable setting in SCSS file but it didn't work..
Please tell me how can if fix that.
thanks.

Comment: A snapshot of your inspect element could help understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a custom row with a custom width?

To do this you can use your own class and and include `grid-row` and then add your own `max-width`.

If this is your html:

```
<div class="custom-row-class">
</div>
```

Then in your scss file, write

```
.custom-row-class {
  @include row-width();
  max-width: 75em;
}
```

Just be aware that if your row is inside another containing `div` it won't be able to get any wider than that, because your custom div has `max-width` which shrinks to the containing div, and `width: 100%` which will also shrink to fit a containing div.

Here are some links to the documentation. I find the Foundation 5 doc is a little easier to understand this. Also have a look at the `_grid.scss` file for more info.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/grid.html#customize-with-sass

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#building-semantically

Answer (score -1):

If you want `row` with `width` equal to the width of the entire view-port, then you can use :

```
<div class="row expanded">
```

If you are using **two** `css` files, check the order in which you have mentioned your `foundation.css` or `foundation.min.css` and your `app.css` or `custom.css`. The `former` should follow the `latter` and not the other way around.

If nothing is working out, you can try:

```
.row
{
  max-width: 80rem !important;
}
```